# How can we show year and quarter wise data in the same visualization in tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have quarter and year wise data when we visualize quarterly data it's showing exactly the same and when we selected year data it's combining all the data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To begin with, can you help to provide additional information like what have you tried, the desired outcome, input etc. That would be a great help and you can get answers quickly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.